# how to use 2 index.php file One for mobile and one for desktop

Tags: php, functions, themes

I want use 2 index.php file in WP, One for mobile and one for desktop. Is there a way for this?
or
use a index.php file with deferent content for mobile and desktop.

There is a solution?

(I dont use media query css or 2 theme)

Answer (score 0):

You can create AMP version of your page for mobile devices.
Please check this tutorial: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/create/basic_markup?format=websites